# (Real)VNC Viewer Dual/Multiple Display at remote pc - toggle display?

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, vnc, tightvnc, realvnc

VNC is a great tool. However with multiple monitors either on client or on server its a bit sub-optimal.

fi. if the server features 2 monitors and the client 2 you got one single window in the viewer that you might strech over two monitors - if they are aligned well and have the same resolution its more or less practicable.

also, this window shows both remote monitors, so you either have to stretch that window to reach over your two viewer monitors or you skale the display window setting to zoom in and scroll around in that viewer window that shows both displays.

Is there a way to either show each remote monitor seperately on the client screens so one is on the left monitor and the other on the right?

Or at least have one monitor fullscreen and toggle between screens with a shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a helper application that does this: https://github.com/jackyaz/DisplaySwitchVNC

EDIT: OK so my application only fulfils OP's final requirement:
"Or at least have one monitor fullscreen and toggle between screens with a shortcut?"

My README https://github.com/jackyaz/DisplaySwitchVNC/blob/master/README.md hopefully covers how to use + how it works

This sounds like it might help with the first 2 points:
https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016572531-How-do-I-use-VNC-Viewer-in-full-screen-mode-on-all-of-my-screens-

Comment: Thanks for contributing here. Could you give a brief explanation of how to use this tool and how it solves the problem?

Comment: Updated my answer